# Why does my program terminate without giving any output in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to compile this code in Java but it terminates without providing any output or errors.

```
public class findEvenQueue {
    public int mysteryMethod(int n) {
        if (n <= 2) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return mysteryMethod(n - 1) + mysteryMethod(n - 2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findEvenQueue a = new findEvenQueue();
        a.mysteryMethod(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! What do you expect it to output?

Comment: Because the program is not printing any output

Comment: Please try with System.out.println(a.mysteryMethod(4));

Comment: Many of my programs terminate without providing any output or errors Idk if I am doing something wrong in my code

Comment: @Noman ali abbasi  i tried System.out.println(a.mysteryMethod(4));  and it worked. Do you know why my code didn't work?

Comment: No problem in your code.... you were not writing your result on console

Comment: @HARSHRAJTHAKOR Your code *did* work. It did run that function and calculate that value, but you never told it to *do* anything with that value, so it just exited once it had finished. Whenever you want your to show something on the screen, you need to use `System.out.println(...)` to print the thing you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not printing anything on the console. Change your code as below

```
public class findEvenQueue {
    public int mysteryMethod(int n) {
        if (n <= 2) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return mysteryMethod(n - 1) + mysteryMethod(n - 2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findEvenQueue a = new findEvenQueue();
        System.out.println(a.mysteryMethod(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried System.out.println(a.mysteryMethod(4)); and it worked. Do you know why my code didn't work?

Comment: That is because you didn't display the returned value. The above fix prints the returned value on the screen.